# i am not defining any service for my ldap project, yet it is suggesting me to create one. Is it necessary to do so?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, autowired

```
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("ldapAuthenticationProvider")
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider' in your configuration.

How to sort out this issue. Please Help

Answer (score -1):

Try to make service class and annotate it with @Service. I think it may be needed